# Is there any way to static_assert that template argument is noncopyable?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, static-assert, noncopyable

Is there any way to determine that some type is non-copyable during compile time? 
I need following:

```
template<typename T, unsigned long long MaxSize>
struct circular_buffer : boost::noncopyable {
    static_assert(typeof(T) ?????, "T must be noncopyable!");
};
```

Comment: Why would it matter if `T` is copyable if you do not copy `T` objects? If you were using copyability to select between different implementations it would make sense, but I can't otherwise imagine why you would want to restrict something to work only with noncopyable objects. Obviously anything you can do with a non-copyable type you could also do with a copyable type.

Comment: @Casey, the T isn't homogenous type - as it's last field, there is char data[0]. I need spsc-lockfree buffer for heterogenous types - and I want it to be as safe as possible

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++11 has the `is_copy_assignable` and `is_copy_constructible` type traits. Assert that both are false.